# how can I improve the deletion of repeated elements from an array of 2D numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I tried to run the code below, but takes a long time, is there any way to improve this code? I tried with a lot of python functions but all look like are created to work with 1D arrays only, sorry for the code I am very new on this:

Function that returns an array that contains unique elements:

```
def get_unique_values(dataset):
    uniqueimages=np.empty(dataset.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    u=0

    for i in range(dataset.shape[0]):
        if (check_if_exists(dataset[i,:,:],uniqueimages)==0):
            uniqueimages[u,:,:]=dataset[i,:,:]
            u=u+1

    return uniqueimages[0:u,:,:]
```

function that verifies if a given element is already in the array:

```
def check_if_exists( q,a ):
    r=0
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        if np.array_equal(q,a[i,:,:]):
            r=1
            break

    return r
```

then I run this giving a 3D array as input (shape= 2000,28,28):

```
vadu=get_unique_values(3Darray)
```

EDIT: this question was solved in the other linked question, thanks Divakar!

Comment: This is very very broad. You can use np.unique() on some flattened view or hash and work on hashes. But that decision is hard to do blindly.

Comment: Thanks Sascha, I tried with np.unique but it compares the 2D arrays not as a whole element but by its internal numbers and the comparison is not accurate. Think that function is more useful with 1D arrays. Will investigate about Hashes and see what can i find

Comment: Again too broad. You should mention if those might differ by shapes and size and if this is relevant here. We don't know that. (and is not accurate sounds strange; this is fully deterministic and correct; but of course it might not be doing what you think it's doing)

Comment: ok, the 3D array is an array of images, so 2D arrays are the elements inside. When I run np.unique it is converting my 3D array to a 1D array with shape (256,). I suponse as the 2D arrays are representing images they contain values only from 0 to 256 and the np.unique is comparing only the numbers not the 2D elements as a whole. Thats why I build the functions.

Comment: Then start by reading the docs, especially the argument: ```axis```.

Comment: Yes, there is no 'axis' parameter in python3 for np.unique. Documentation says that "Parameter: Input array - This will be flattened if it is not already 1-D."
Don't know how to fix this really.

Comment: The `axis` argument was added to `unique` in numpy 1.13.0.

Comment: Thanks all!, as marked by Divakar, this question was perfectly answered in the linked question.
But don't have a way to mark this as solved with a linked question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the unique elements from a numpy array, you can use the numpy `unique` function.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,2,3,4,2,4])
np.unique(a)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: I tried that I I got the 3D array converted to a 1D array.
>>trd.shape
(200000, 28, 28)
>>newarray=np.unique(trd)
>>v.shape
(256,)

I want to tell that the 3D array contains images as 2D arrays, so the values are from 0 to 256 each element. Dont know why is converting the original array to a 1D array.
Thats why I built the functions above